# why valid-invalid bit is needed in simple paging system?

Tags: operating-systems

I am learning OS from Silberschatz book. I read the [Valid-invalid bit in a process page table](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18293/valid-invalid-bit-in-a-process-page-table) also. But I could not understand why valid-invalid bit is required. The pagetable is dynamically built as pages are mapped to frames. So all the entries in page-table are valid.

thanks

Comment: Both the linked question and this question make the false assumption that the table will only have as many entries as there are valid pages. Even when using a hash table to store entries, there will typically be empty slots. A mechanism must be provided to distinguish an unfilled slot (which can still be indexed/accessed) from a valid page entry; valid bits are one such mechanism.

Comment: Multiple duplicates: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18293/valid-invalid-bit-in-a-process-page-table http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66541/what-is-the-need-for-valid-invalid-bit-in-paged-memory-technique

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the need for valid/invalid bit in paged memory technique?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66541/what-is-the-need-for-valid-invalid-bit-in-paged-memory-technique)